# Mapping alt keys in Vim on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

I have a function that I'd like to map to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> in gVim on Windows (7.3.46 32 bit Bram@KIBAALE Big version on Win7-x64) and it's... not working.

My .vimrc has a line that reads:

```
nnoremap <A-o> :call SplitRelatedFile()<CR>
```

Then I fire up gVim, load up a file, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and get a beep.  I tried with a capital O in the mapping, I tried with and without shift in gVim, and it's just not working, I just get beeps.  (I've also tried `<M-o>`.)

If I load up Vim in the terminal, it works as expected.  If I manually execute the above line in a new instance of gVim, it also works as expected.  It's only not working when it appears in the .vimrc.  Actually, it appears in another file but my _vimrc just has one line that reads `source x:/path/to/my.vimrc`.

When I look at the output of `:map` I don't get alt keys listed as alt keys anyway, presumably due to the 8th bit interpretation crossing something up.  However what I do see is...

```
n  <ef>        * :call SplitRelatedFile()<CR>
```

and after I manually run the `:nnoremap` in gVim I see this (the first line shows i-umlaut as the key if there are any character translation issues with this post):

```
n  ï           * :call SplitRelatedFile()<CR>
n  <ef>        * :call SplitRelatedFile()<CR>
```

So it seems that the 8th bit is getting interpreted differently at different points in Vim's (GUI) startup?  For what it's worth, when I run `:map` in console Vim I get the i-umlaut as well and not the `<ef>` line (`o` is 0x6F in ASCII so would be 0xEF if the high bit is set, so this makes perfect sense; i-umlaut seems to be 0x8B).

I've tried a few different <kbd>Alt</kbd> key combinations and none of them have survived into gVim so I'm curious if anyone's got any tips.  Maybe I can stuff these somehow into a "delayed load" module of some sort, like a local plugin or something?

I could move away from <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys but I'm out of function keys and don't want to stomp on the obvious <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys for this functionality...  I just discovered that I could replace the `<A-o>` with the result of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and that does work (as I get the i-umlaut in my vimrc) but that's not very nice!  Any thoughts on this madness?  (Oh and this doesn't work for console Vim, I need to keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd> versions for when `has("gui")` returns false.)

I've now noticed that both gVim and console Vim report the i-umlaut as 0xEF so ... I don't know what I need to do to make this less kludgey.  Help me please!

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you (or some plugin) modify `'encoding'` at some point? After that, the previous mappings may not work any more.

Comment: LOL I just realized that and come here to comment and see your query.  `encoding` is latin1 when the vimrc is parsed but then becomes utf-8 at some point...  Indeed it is changed in my gvimrc.  I wonder if there's any reason for it to be there rather than in the vimrc (it's one of the few remaining lines of config that I copied from a coworker when I started using Vim three+ years ago)...

Comment: Ah, great to see my hunch confirmed! I've expanded my comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mappings (especially combinations with <kbd>Alt</kbd> that have the 8th bit set) are susceptible to changes of `'encoding'`, and may break when you later modify it.

As a general rule, if you want to `:set encoding=...`, it should be one of the first things in your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: In other words, don't set your `encoding` setting in the gvimrc.  :)  Thanks.

Comment: In Neovim (https://neovim.io), mapping the alt key "Just Works", in the terminal as well as in GUIs such as neovim-qt.